# Problema com navegação entre páginas com outcome

Tags: jsf

Tenho uma aplicação JSF onde há um template dentro de WEB-INF e as outras páginas na raiz WebContent.

No Template há vários links apontando cada um para a sua entidade e nesta página de destino há chamadas para página de inclusão e lista.

Estavam funcionado perfeitamente mas não estavam organizadas em pastas.

Então para organizar as minhas páginas criei uma pasta dentro de WebContent com o nome páginas e dentro criei as pastas das respectivas entidades e nesta as páginas que são 3:
a página que recebe do link do template e aponta para inclusão e lista, a página de inclusão e a página de lista.

ex:) 
template: link localidade;
localidade.xhtml
cadastro-localidade.xhtml
lista-localidades.xhtml

usando navegação implícita:

o problema é que somente a página que escolho para abrir quando o usuário é logado com sucesso fica o link na tela porque é redirecionada pela aplicação, as outras ficam o nome mas quando passo o mouse não fica a mãozinha continua a seta como fosse um outputText mas com a cor do link (azul).

usando navegação explícita:

fazendo a configuração no faces-config.xml e trocando o outcome por action nos links o links são gerados na página mas não redireciona para a pasta de destino.

como faço para ter as páginas organizadas em pastas fazendo a navegação de todas as páginas pelos link onde a aplicação somente redirecionar para uma apenas após o login com sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Além dessas tem a página de autenticação que está na raiz na pasta WebContent e template que está em WEB-INF/templates. Então ao executar a aplicação irá acessar a tela de autenticação configurada no web.xml(welcome-file) e o template tem os links de navegação apontando para as telas localidade.xhtml,contrato.xhtml,servico.xhtml,fornecedor.xhtml etc. e estas chamando as listas e os formulários de insersão.

Comment: Tira um print das sua estrutura de arquivos, e manda o código dos links/ botoes que vc chama as outras paginas

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: você usa linux? se sim, por acaso vc criou essas pastas na "mao"? ou pela " IDE"? se for na "mao" verifique as permissões.

Comment: não uso linux. Criei as pastas pela IDE Eclipse.